# Showing different views when a listview is empty or has no internet connectivity or has a loading status

Tags: android, listview, layout

I need to fetch a JSON array from a web service and populate a listview. I need to show a different views when:

1. the list is loading
2. there is no connectivity
3. the list is empty

At the moment, I am using different linearlayouts and playing with the visibility to achieve this. What would be the optimal way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Bound Service. I did the something similar in my application. Where upon clicking refresh, I invoke a service which gets data in background and updates the UI.

Check out my service here:
https://github.com/madhur/GAnalytics/blob/develop/src/in/co/madhur/ganalyticsdashclock/AnalyticsDataService.java

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(AnalyticsAccountResult result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    App.getEventBus().post(result);
}
```

Activity:
https://github.com/madhur/GAnalytics/blob/develop/src/in/co/madhur/ganalyticsdashclock/MainActivity.java

```
@Subscribe
public void UpdateUI(AnalyticsAccountResult result) {
    ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbHeaderProgress);
    LinearLayout spinnerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.spinnerslayout);
    TextView statusMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusMessage);

    switch (result.getStatus()) {
        case STARTING:
        statusMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        spinnerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;

        case FAILURE:
        statusMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spinnerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        statusMessage.setText(result.getErrorMessage());
        break;

        case SUCCESS:
        statusMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spinnerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (result.getItems() != null)
        {
            this.acProfiles = result.getItems();
            MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(acProfiles, this);
            listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            UpdateSelectionPreferences();
            if (result.isPersist() && acProfiles.size() > 0)
            {
                if (App.LOCAL_LOGV)
                Log.v(App.TAG, "saving configdata");        
                try
                {
                    appPreferences.saveConfigData(acProfiles, credential.getSelectedAccountName());
                }
                catch (JsonProcessingException e)
                {
                    Log.e(App.TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

It would also helpful to use Otto library:
http://square.github.io/otto/